# Why does my text keep highlighting?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text, highlighting, toast

I am making a "toast" in vb.net, and whenever it pops up, all the text in the body textbox is ALWAYS highlighted...how can I remove the highlight programmatically?

Thanks!

Here is the code which seems to be automatically highlighting:

```
Dim i As Integer
        toast.HeaderL.Text = headertext
        toast.BodyL.Text = contenttext
        toast.Show()
        toast.Opacity = 0
        i = 0
        While i < 100
            toast.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right - toast.Width, My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Bottom - ((toast.Height / 100) * i))
            toast.Opacity += 0.01
            wait(7)
            i += 1
        End While
        wait(4000)
        toast.Opacity = 1
        i = 0
        While i < 100
            toast.SetDesktopLocation(toast.Location.X, toast.Location.Y + toast.Height / 100)
            toast.Opacity -= 0.01
            wait(7)
            i += 1
        End While
        toast.Close()
```

Always, the text inside BodyL (which is a textbox), highlights itself.I tried adding in toast.Focus() at some points, but that did not work.

toast is the form name.

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  ASP.NET and JavaScript?  We need a lot more information than you're giving us here.

Comment: Winforms, vb.net 2008, made in Visual Basic express with sp1

Comment: Can you share some code, showing what you do?

Comment: Added it. Hopefully its enough to help you answer the question lol!

Comment: What kind of control is `toast`?

Comment: Its a winform, with FormBorderStyle set to "none"

Comment: And BodyL is a textbox, with scrollbars set to "vertical" and which is readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more of a guess, but you could try to add the following line, after assigning the text to `BodyL`:

```
toast.BodyL.Select(toast.BodyL.Text.Length, 0)
```

Another idea is to add some other control to the toast form (such as a `Panel`) that can receive input focus without showing (it can be made very tiny, or even have it moved outside the visible part of the form), and making sure that that control receives focus when the toast form is displayed.